# No wireless connection in newly installed Ubuntu with BCM4312

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

I just installed Ubuntu on my machine and there is no wireless connection. I mean, the wireless card won't even show at the top pane of my desktop.

I might also add that whenever the Ubuntu launches, a moment before I get the login screen, there are three lines that say:

```
ERROR... something... something... wireless... go to www.kernel... something...
```

I don't know the exact words in the errors, because it vanishes a second after it appears, and it's too fast for me to read.

Is there a command that can detect my wireless card specification so I can look for a driver? or better yet, is there a command that can download the necessary drivers for the wireless card?

Here are the results for `ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 88:ae:1d:33:93:b0  
          inet addr:10.0.0.5  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8aae:1dff:fe33:93b0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3539 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2922 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3317067 (3.3 MB)  TX bytes:332509 (332.5 KB)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1119 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1119 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:110448 (110.4 KB)  TX bytes:110448 (110.4 KB)
```

If any more information is needed, tell me.

Please, this is very important to me, I have a project due next week, and I cannot do it without wireless (I'm connected through wired connection right now).

EDIT:
Here's some more information that might help, `lspci -nn | grep 0280` gives:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it! :)
I found [this](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/796), and it solved my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure; does it show any wireless driver installed?, what brand of computer are you using, i had a similar problem with a Dell and the issue was easily fixed by un- installing the wireless driver (without installing it again) sounds weird but it actually worked

Comment: No, it seems like there is no wireless driver installed, since the wireless card won't show anywhere... not in the top pane of the desktop, and not in the system settings (as the picture in the comment to @user312240 shows).